# Use regex in vim to to replace with incrementing variable but reinitialize this variable at a specific word

Tags: replace, increment, ex, reinitialization

I have for the moment the following ex command:

```
:let a = 1 | g/B/ s//\=printf('%02d', a)/ | let a += 1
```

This command replace each occurrence of `B` by an incremented number.  But, each time the word `reinitialize` appear in the file, a variable should be set at 0, without modifying noting to the word `reinitialize`. The variable should only affect the occurrences of `B`.

I can add at the end `| g/reinitialize/ let a = 0`. But this occur the replacement of the only first occurrence of `B` and ignore all the following ones.

How to do this?